# "-2" Postfix added at the end of the permalink

Tags: permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, debug

I know -2 comes due to having duplicate names either in post/pages or media files.

But I don't have any such duplicate name. In fact, I tried installing WordPress from scratch and tried to create a page permalink like following:

mysite.com/area-codes/432
I kept the permalink to number.

Area codes is parent page and 432 is child one to that. But it gives the structure after saving the draft as follows:
mysite.com/area-codes/432-2

I'm quite confused. Also if I don't make any page parent or child and create a standard page with number permalink like below:
mysite.com/432

it still gives the same result:
mysite.com/432-2

How to overcome this? Why its happening?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, It answers my question. I also resolved the problem using a plugin called "Allow Numeric Slugs". But I want to know what are the disadvantages of allowing it? Am I going to face any issues later on?

Comment: If any of your area code posts end up as the same number as a valid year (eg, `2023`), you might run into unexpected consequences. It might be wise to check with the plugin's support team and see if they've got an answer to your question.